# Font Awesome in PHTML file

Tags: php, magento, font-awesome

I would like to show the check icon on the page on the Magento order success page. However, the icon does not appear with the implemented code. Do I need to add the php code in order for the icon to appear?

[image]

```
<div><span class=fa faSuccess fa-check-circle-o fa-5x>&nbsp;</span></div>
```

Thank you

Comment: i think that the **success** icon is called `fa-success` instead of faSuccess, but as you are using magento and i know nothing about that i can't be sure

Comment: Thanks @DannyG faSuccess is my css styling code for the check mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add double quotes for class

```
<div><span class="fa faSuccess fa-check-circle-o fa-5x">&nbsp;</span></div>
```